# How to simulate NVL in HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I tried this:

```
from Table where (:par1 is null or col1 = :par1)
```

but it happens that

```
from Table where :par1 is null
```

always returns all the rows of the table, even if the :par1 is not null.

while

```
 select * from table where col1 = 'asdf'
```

does not return any row.

I can't use native grammars because my application is supposed to run on different database engines

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The equivalent to the `nvl` command in HQL is the `coalesce` command.  `coalesce(a,b)` will return `a` if `a` is not null, otherwise `b`.

So you would want something on the lines of:

```
from Table where col1 = coalesce(:par1, 'asdf')
```

Comment: What I wanted in fact was:
from Table where col1 = coalesce(:par1, col1)

and it worked! thanks a lot!

Comment: coalesce() is also an ANSI SQL function, and should work on most databases, e.g. Oracle, natively.

Comment: also in jpa entity named query it did not work with nvl but worked with coalesce

Answer (score 3):

If your underlying database is Oracle then you can use the nvl function, I tried it and it worked for me.

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
                    " select ft from FeatureToggle ft left outer join ft.featureToggleCustomerMap "
                    + " ftcm where nvl(ftcm.custId,:custId) = :custId");

query.setParameter("custId", Long.valueOf(custId));
```

Your use case can be diffrent and you can use the nvl function as per your requirement if the database is nvl, not sure about the implecation of the other databases, as I have used this code only for Oracle.
Hope it helps.

Comment: The OP has mentioned that the app has to run on different databases. In which case, this is not the answer expected.