# Ordering by varying columns in JPQL/Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a table of Sessions. Each session has "session_start_time" and "session_end_time". While the session is open, the end time is empty. I want to fetch the list of sessions, and order it by the following logic:

1. If the session is open (no end time), order by the start time.
2. If the session is closed, order by the end time.

Something like:

```
 ORDER BY (session_end_time == null) ? session_start_time : session_end_time
```

I'm using JPA and JPQL for the queries, and using Hibernate for the execution. What would you recommend?

**NOTE**: I would rather not add CASE to the SELECT, but instead keep it clean so I get a list of sessions without additional unneeded fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORDER BY nvl(session_end_time, session_start_time)

nvl is an Oracle function. I'm sure ther are functions like that for other DBMS

Found this one for hibernate:
nvl in HIBERNATE: [How to simulate NVL in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601615/how-to-simulate-nvl-in-hql)

ORDER BY: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=997220&start=0

Comment: This helps, thanks! Coalesce does work, and is faster than using CASE. I need to verify that it works in JPQL as well (tested on SQL so far).

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN session_end_time IS NULL THEN session_start_time 
    ELSE session_end_time 
END
```

work in your DBMS? That doesn't add a field.

Otherwise you can calculate it inside a nested query, but don't include it in the final `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM (
    SELECT field1, field2, CASE WHEN session_end_time... END AS dummyfield
) Q
ORDER BY Q.dummyfield
```

Comment: The CASE does work on PostgreSQL. Seems like your other option adds an additional column to the result set, which I like to avoid. In comparison with COALESCE, the CASE performs slower though (1.7ms for no ordering, 5.61 for coalesce, 6.89 for case), so I may go with Coalesce.

Comment: The other option doesn't add another column because the computed column is not mentioned in the `SELECT` clause. `COALESCE` is fine to use instead of `CASE` in this problem, I just didn't think of it...

Comment: Oh oh right, I see it now! That's another interesting approach, however I can't seem to be able to do it along with selecting "*", which is what I want to do in JPQL.