# how to get empty value using HQL for refering object id if refering object is NULL

Tags: hibernate, hql

My HQL select query is like below

```
     select user.id, user.address.id from User user
```

In this query, if ***user.address*** is **NULL** then query does not return that User record.

My requirement is, **if user.address is NULL then user.address.id should return all User record with '' (empty value) for user.address.id.**  and records should be like below

[1,''], [2,1], [3,'']...

Answer (score 3):

Faced similar problem today.
The problem here is that hibernate will produce `inner join address` SQL.

```
select user0_.id as col_0_0_, address1_.id as col_1_0_ from user user0_
    inner join address address1_ on user0_.address_id=address1_.id
```

As the result of inner join you will lose all the records where address is null. Use explicit left join to achieve what you need. HQL:

```
select user.id, addr.id from User user left join user.address addr
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the exact answer for such stuff.

```
select user.id, case when user.address is null then '' else user.address.id end 
from User user
```

this case clause in select clause works like if else

```
if (user.address == null)
   return "";
else
   return user.address.id;
```

in this way you will get all records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'coalesce' command (like the "nvl" SQL command).

As can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601615/how-to-simulate-nvl-in-hql):

> The equivalent to the nvl command in HQL is the coalesce command. coalesce(a,b) will return a if a is not null, otherwise b.
>
> So you would want something on the lines of:
>
> from Table where col1 = coalesce(:par1, 'asdf')

Edit:
In your case I assume you are looking for something like:

> select user.id, coalesce(user.address.id, '') from User user

Comment: if user.address is NULL then its not returning User record. :(

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only case, you can do something like this:

```
select user.id, user.address.id from User user
```

This will give you all records when `user.address` is not null.

You can now have this, to have the rest of the records:

```
select user.id, '' from User user when user.addresss is null
```

Comment: making two queries is not always a natural choice e.g. if there are more than one such field in question (user.address.id, user.contact.mobile, user.preferences.private etc)