# How to achieve the following sql query using HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I've the following sql query which I need to accommodate using HQL.

A is an Author and B is an Book - Author has Many books

SQL:

```
order by a.bookNbr desc, nvl(b.auth_name, b.last_name || ' ' || b.first_name))
```

Any help would be appreciated to convert above sql to HQL.

Comment: Take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601615/how-to-simulate-nvl-in-hql

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
order by a.bookNbr desc, coalesce(b.auth_name, b.last_name + " " + b.first_name))
```